# How to pass a value from a SwiftUI view TO a textfield in another view

Tags: swiftui

I am attempting to modify a basic SwiftUI to do list app with navigationlinks for each generated list item. When clicking on the link and navigating to a separate DetailView, I want the text of the list item that is clicked to pass directly TO a textfield in the DetailView, as a precursor to updating the list item text. So far, I have managed to set up the navigationlinks in the content view list to pass the list item text to the DetailView. Then, in the DetailView, I set up the textField to receive the list item text by binding the textfield in the DetailView to the model ("Todo"). However, I ended up having to set the model in the detail view as @State ex.`@State var detail: Todo`. Is setting the model instance in DetailView to @State a correct practice? If not, what would be the correct way to pass the list item text from the navigationlink in ContentView to the textField in DetailView? See my Code Below:

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var todoListVM = TodoListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
               
                TextField("Enter title", text: $todoListVM.todoTitle)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                
                Button("Add Task") {
                    todoListVM.createTodoItem()
                    todoListVM.todoTitle = ""
                }.padding(.top, 10)
                
                List {
                    ForEach(todoListVM.todoItems) { todoItem in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(viewModel: todoListVM, detail: todoItem), label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text(todoItem.title)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }.onAppear(perform: {
                    todoListVM.populateTodos()
                })
                
                .navigationTitle("Todos")
            
            }.padding()
    }
}
```

DetailView

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TodoListViewModel
    
    @State var detail: Todo
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter Text", text: $detail.title)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .padding(.all, 10)
        Spacer()        
        Button("Update") {
            viewModel.updateTodoItem(for: detail.title)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.5))
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        
    }
}
```

TodoListViewModel

```
class TodoListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var todoTitle: String = ""
    @Published var todoItems = [Todo]()
    
    func createTodoItem() {
        let todo = Todo(title: todoTitle)
        Webservice().createTodoItem(url: Constants.Urls.createTodoURL, todo: todo) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    if let response = response {
                        if response.success {
                            self.populateTodos()
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateTodoItem(for newTitle: String) {
        let todo = Todo(title: newTitle)
        Webservice().updateTodoItem(url: Constants.Urls.updateTodoURL, todo: todo) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    if let response = response {
                        if response.success {
                            self.populateTodos()
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
        
    func populateTodos() {
        Webservice().getAllTodos(url: Constants.Urls.allTodosURL) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let todos):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.todoItems = todos.map{$0}
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Todo (Model)

```
struct Todo: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var title: String = ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Detail view should use an `@Binding`, not `@State` for `var detail: ToDo`.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TodoListViewModel

    // Use @Binding instead of @State
    @Binding var detail: Todo
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter Text", text: $detail.title)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .padding(.all, 10)
        Spacer()        
        Button("Update") {
            viewModel.updateTodoItem(for: detail.title)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.5))
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        
    }
}
```

You should never pass in to an @State in a detail view. If you need to change the variable such as with your `TextField` you use `@Binding` to create a two way connection. Otherwise, if it is just display, pass it to a `let` constant.

Comment: thanks! I will attempt to add shorter examples in the future. In the meantime, when I change the DetailView to use ```@Binding var detail: Todo```, the parameter in the NavigationLink that passes the todoItem index for Todo into the DetailView is now expecting ```Binding<Todo>``` instead of just Todo. I tried passing todoItem into that binding, like so: ```Binding<todoItem>```, but that did not work

Comment: You pass it in as `$todo`. I would also go through [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) and [Stanford's CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu). They cover all of this in detail.

Comment: hi @JS_is_awesome18, Have you solve it? because changing todo to $todo will have another error which is 'Cannot find '$todo' in scope'.

Comment: That is because the ForEach needs to be set up properly, in this case `ForEach(todoListVM.$todoItems) { $todoItem in`.